# Command Prompt creating help for command unsuccessful

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Code :

```
:echo
if not "%1"=="/?" (
echo %*
) else (
echo ECHO :
echo Write line.
echo.
echo Syntax :
echo echo [text]
)
goto :start
```

I placed it in my Command Line interface.
But when I use `call :echo /?`, it was unsuccessful.
What can i do? Should I use `-?` instead of `/?`?

Comment: You could use -?.  The problem is that /? has a special meaning when you use it with call.  It prints the help for the call command.

Comment: I see. Should i close the question??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cup diagnosed the problem in his comment. The CALL command is interpretting the `/?` as a request for help on the CALL command itself.

You could change the 2nd line in your script to read:

```
if not "%~1"=="/?" (
```

And then when you CALL the routine, use:

```
call :echo "/?"
```